# Qt Migration from MSVC to MinGW - COM Object Issues

Tags: c++, com, qt5, mingw

I'm attempting to migrate my Qt application over to using the MinGW toolchain from the MSVC toolchain.

The application uses a COM object, making use of the `#import` directive supported by the MSVC compiler however, as MinGW does not support this, I'm trying to figure out what I need to do in order to bring in this COM object.

What I've done so far is:

1. Use `dumpcpp` to generate a `.h` and `.cpp` file for the `.tlb` file
2. Add `axcontainer` to the list of QT modules in the `.pro` file
3. Added both the resulting `.h` and `.cpp` to my Qt project

Having instantiated some classes from within the COM library, I can get my project to compile however there seems to be a large number of warnings along the lines of:

```
can't find linker symbol for virtual table for `ENCX::IS57Manager' value
found `guard variable for (anonymous namespace)::Q_QGS_qAccessibleFactories::innerFunction()::holder' instead
QAxBase::qt_metacall: Object is not initialized, or initialization failed

mincore\com\oleaut32\typelib\tlibapi.cpp(2279)\OLEAUT32.dll!74D65126: (caller: 74D64EC5) ReturnHr(1) tid(c7e8) 8002801D Library not registered.
```

I think my main issue is that I have no idea what the above means.

Things I have also done:

1. Called `CoInitialize` although I think my `QApplication` already does this
2. Included the `dll` alongside the `exe` build for the application
3. Ensured that the `dll` is registered in the system using `regsvr32`